# ALSA and Mednafen: No Sound

Tags: alsa, emulation

I am getting no sound in Mednafen on Linux MInt 17.1 Mate 64-bit. Relevant part of 
`~/.mednafen/mednafen.cfg` are:

```
;Disable speed throttling when sound is disabled.
nothrottle 0

;Automatically save and load save states when a game is closed or loaded, respectively.
autosave 0

;Select sound driver.
sounddriver default

;Select sound output device.
sounddevice default

;Sound volume level, in percent.
soundvol 100

;Enable sound emulation.
sound 1

;If non-zero, specifies the desired period size in microseconds.  Currently only affects OSS and ALSA output.
sound.period_time 0

;Specifies the desired size of the sound buffer, in milliseconds.
soundbufsize 32

;Specifies the sound playback rate, in frames per second("Hz").
 soundrate 48000
```

Relevant part of output when starting Mednafen from command line is:

```
Initializing sound...
  Using "ALSA" audio driver with device "default":ALSA Error: snd_pcm_open(&alsa_pcm, id ? id : "hw:0", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0) No such file or directory
Error opening a sound device.
```

I have alsa-base installed, do I need something else too? Any ideas?

Comment: Does `aplay something.wav` work?

Comment: @CL. Yes, it did.

Answer (score 9):

Just set

```
sounddevice sexyal-literal-default
```

FYI:
http://mednafen.sourceforge.net/documentation/mednafen.html#Core+Features%01Troubleshooting+and+Common+Solutions%01No+sound+output+on+Linux.

Comment: I got it to work by adding the line sounddevice sexyal-literal-default to the end of the file ~/.mednafen/mednafen-09x.cfg

Comment: It is: `sound.device sexyal-literal-default`

Comment: And now the file is `~/.mednafen/mednafen.cfg`.

Answer (score 4):

Select sound driver

```
sounddriver sdl
```

That worked for me: Ubuntu 12.04

If you put something wrong in it will output a list of options in terminal when run. Mine options for sounddriver: also,oss,sdl,jack,dummy

Comment: sdl is laggier than the default alsa driver for me.